# Можно ли использовать во Flask темплейт, который расположен в отдельном pip модуле?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Есть приложение на фласке. Оно через pip использует отдельный модуль (который в отдельном git репозитории), в котором помимо кода на питоне есть html шаблоны. Возможно ли использовать этот "внешний" шаблон?

Цель данного вопроса, чтобы реализовать следующую задачу: Есть много микросервисов, основанные на Flask. И все они имеют несколько общих шаблонов, которые хотелось бы хранить в отдельном общем модуле, а не дублировать код.

Answer (score 1):

Код не дам, но `PackageLoader` ( http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#loaders) должен решить вашу задачу.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.jinja_loader - а этот аттрибут отвечает за установку лоадера.

Comment: Благодарствую, вроде как оно. Попробую этот лодер.

Comment: Ну если это оно, то пометьте как решение чтобы другие  об этом тоже  знали.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте какой-то шаблонизатор для python, чтобы можно было легко подключать пути ко всем шаблонам и подключать нужный.

Например [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/)

Comment: Я и использую jinja2. Просьба показать пример, как я могу использовать шаблон который в другом, отдельном pip модуле. Я не знаю точного пути к этому шаблону, он где-то в папке venv виртуального окружения.